# Use IP instead of domain in Cpanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

I have access to a CPanel associated with a primary domain name `www.test.com` and it's IP is `55.666.777.888`.

However, we must point the domain to another IP address temporarily and do some set-up on this server at the same time. The issue is I cannot access `55.666.777.888` to set up WordPress after having redirected `www.test.com` to another IP. The domain must always serve another website in the mean while.

When I visit the Domain page, `www.test.com` is still listed as primary domain.

Is there anyway that we can disable the domain temporarily and access the site using the IP then revert it later?

Comment: You don't need to change anything on your webserver, just use a client-side tool like PostMan or a browser-extension that lets you use an explicit `Host:`  header in requests.

Comment: That said, you should give every website a fallback, fail-safe, hostname URL that people can use besides the main public domain name - that means you can avoid this problem entirely.